# Delete Contents of Cell Based on First Character - VBA BEGINNER

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code to clear the contents of any cells in column B which has a quotation mark " as the first character. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So where are you stuck?  Please show what you have done.

Comment: Use `If Instr( Cells(1,1) , chr(34)) = 1 then Cells(1,1) = ""`

Comment: Or use `Left` on the first character... Hint: `If Left(Rng.Value, 1) = chr(34)` Then

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub KlearUp()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rKill As Range
    Set rng = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In rng
        If Left(r.Value, 1) = Chr(34) Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(r, rKill)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rKill Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rKill.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If the cells contain formulas rather than constants, then replace:

```
Set rng = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

with:

```
Set rng = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't changing anything when I run it. The text in the cells I'm trying to delete starts with a " but has text after such as "text"

Comment: Actually there are formulas in these cells.. will that make a difference? These cells have the CONCATENATE() function in them..

Comment: @RS  See my **EDIT#1**